# VTK move image to center of the bounding box

Tags: vtk

How can I move my image which is in the bottom left of the bounding box to center of the box? Also I want to maximize the size of the image that fits to the bounding box.

Comment: See if this answer helps on the first issue: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15394359/2345165

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "bounding box"?  If you are using a vtkImageSlice, you can just use SetPosition(-width/2, -height/2, 0).