# Centering image in VTK window

Tags: vtk

I'm using vtkTexturedActor2D and vtkImageMapper to display a 2D image. I can use

```
actor.GetPositionCoordinate().SetCoordinateSystemToNormalizedDisplay();
actor.this.Actor.SetPosition(0.5, 0.9);
```

to place the image in the center of the window, but it's not center-aligned. The corner of the image is placed in the center. How can I center-align the image so that the center of the image is at the center of the window?

Comment: Don't you know the height and width of your image so you can calculate where to place the corner so that the center is centered?

Comment: did you tried renderer->ResetCamera() before rendering window update?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem.

This seems to solve it:

```
  float height, width;
  this->d_actor->GetPositionCoordinate()->SetCoordinateSystemToNormalizedViewport();
  this->d_actor->GetPositionCoordinate()->SetViewport(this); // Without this was getting weird results
  height = this->d_actor->GetHeight();
  width = this->d_actor->GetWidth();
  this->d_actor->GetPositionCoordinate()->SetValue(.5 - width/2.0, .5 - height/2.0);
```